# How can I select 'last business day of the month' in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to subset a DataFrame on the condition that is the last of the month. I used:

```
df['Month_End'] = df.index.is_month_end
sample = df[df['Month_End'] == 1]
```

This works, but I'm working with stock market data, so I'm missing all the instances where the actual end of the month is during the weekend, I need a way to select the "last business day of the month".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can generate a [time series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html) with the last business day of each month by passing in `freq='BM'`.

For example, to create a series of the last business days of 2014:

```
>>> pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=12, freq='BM')
[2014-01-31 00:00:00, ..., 2014-12-31 00:00:00]
Length: 12, Freq: BM, Timezone: None
```

You could then use this timeseries to subset/reindex your DataFrame.

Comment: This solution works. The only issue is that in some series, the last business day of the month could be a 'custom holiday', so you would need to factor that into the equation.

Comment: I am using the accepted answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644857/pandas-dataframe-get-rows-where-index-matches-a-certain-condition but is there a better way to `subset/reindex`?

Comment: The comment from hernanavella is critical. How do we go about this simple question in Python? We just want a clean and easy implementation of this simple question: last stock trading day of a month.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating the series, you can also parse the business month end from your datetime index as this:

```
df['BMonthEnd'] = (df.index + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)).day
```

Though note this currently throws a harmless warning - see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#using-offsets-with-series-datetimeindex

Note: if day (`d`) is already the last business day of the month then `d + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)` will give the last business day of the following month. If this is undesired, use `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0)` instead:

```
df['BMonthEnd'] = (df.index + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0)).day
```

**Edit:**
To actually filter the df as requested by OP:

```
df = df[(df.index + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0)).day == df.index.day]
```

Comment: Note, that this method is not perfect. If day "d" is the last business day of the month then d+BMonthEnd(1) gives you the last business day of the following month.

Answer (score 0):

This is to filter the last business day of each month from your DataFrame object given the index is of datetime type.
`df.resample('BM').mean()`