# Sub setting the Last Business Day of Month for data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, finance

I have a below Data Frame and would like to subset the dataframe which has the last business day of the month to separate data frame.

df = 

        `Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2007-06-18  0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 1591888
1   2007-06-29  0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 88440
2   2007-06-20  0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 3538
3   2007-06-21  0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 3550
4   2007-06-22  0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 670`

df_output =

`Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
1   2007-06-29  0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 88440`

I have tried  `df = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d') + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)` but is not working and I have looked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218543/how-can-i-select-last-business-day-of-the-month-in-pandas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but did not find the right approach. Can anyone help me in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
# in case Date is not in datetime format:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df_output = df.loc[df.Date.isin(df.Date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1))]
```

This returns:

```
>>> df_output
        Date     Open     High      Low    Close  Adj Close  Volume
1 2007-06-29  0.33074  0.33074  0.33074  0.33074    0.33074   88440
```

**Explanation**:

`df.Date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)` returns a series of the last business day in each month for which you have data:

```
>>> df.Date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)
0   2007-06-29
1   2007-07-31
2   2007-06-29
3   2007-06-29
4   2007-06-29
```

Then, you use `loc` to locate any rows in your dataframe in which the actual `Date` is in that series (using [`.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html))

Comment: This is what I am looking for.. Can you please explain what's going on?

Comment: Yes It does explain